# Querying Timedelta df column

Tags: pandas

```
#return rows that are <= 1 hour
df = df[df['timedeltas'].dt.total_seconds() < 3600]
```

After this query I am left with rows that are `Timedelta(-1 days, +23:00:00)`

And even when I compare `pd.Timedelta(days=-1,hours=23) <= pd.Timedelta(hours=1)` I get `True`. How come?

I am looking for a way to exclude any rows that are => 1 hour (01:00:00). Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They indeed have -3600 seconds, it is kind of strange but makes sense depending on where is your 0, note that `pd.Timedelta(days=-1,hours=23)` is the same as `pd.Timedelta(hours=-1)` so if you have your origin in midnight from 01/04/2020 to 02/04/2020 this `pd.Timedelta(days=-1,hours=23)` would mean 23:00 01/04/2020, if you want to remove them, do like this:

```
df = df[(df['timedeltas'].dt.total_seconds() < 3600) & (df['timedeltas'].dt.total_seconds() >= 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, will this remove ones where I have -1days + 00:59:00? Because these still fall under my condition of <= 1hour

Comment: Yes remove all those where the timedelta is negative, in this case -1days +59:00, but note that, for example, pd.Timedelta(days=1, hours=-23) doesn't have a negative timedelta since it is the same as 1 hour!

Comment: Understood thank you, but I need to keep -1 + 59:00 because it's still within one hour. It's just a situation where start is 01/01/20 23:59:00 and end 01/02/20 00:58:00.

Comment: Sorry I mean that just as an example situation. So if  I  had lets say  01/01/20 23:30:00 and end 01/02/20 00:30:00 then I should set the total to -3600 correct?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210876/discussion-between-asleniovas-and-bruno-mello).